# How to consume WebSocket data using Apache Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, spring-websocket

I am new to WebSockets, my requirement is need to consume the data from the WebSocket, using Apache Flink. I am not sure Apache Flink  will support to read the data from the WebSocket or not ?

Here is the reference document that I have followed to implement this job [Reference](https://gist.github.com/tonvanbart/17dc93be413f7c53b76567e10b87a141)

Comment: You can always use a custom source. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code you've shared might work. What's the problem / question?